# OpenSessionInViewFilter not working after migrating Spring 1.2.8/Hibernate 3.1 to Spring 3.1/Hibernate 4.0

Tags: hibernate, spring

We are using `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in our JSF 1.1 web application which is using Spring 1.2.8 and Hibernate 3.1. The filter was working fine. Now, we migrated to Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.0. We are getting the following error.

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Cannot get value for expression '#{infobardisplay.projectList}'
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:405)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.internalGetSelectItemList(RendererUtils.java:450)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getSelectItemList(RendererUtils.java:428)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils.internalRenderSelect(HtmlRendererUtils.java:294)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils.renderMenu(HtmlRendererUtils.java:267)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlMenuRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlMenuRendererBase.java:59)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:539)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.encodeEnd(UIComponentTag.java:498)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.doEndTag(UIComponentTag.java:366)
    at org.apache.jsp.infobar_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fselectOneMenu_005f0(infobar_jsp.java:244)
    at org.apache.jsp.infobar_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f0(infobar_jsp.java:152)
    at org.apache.jsp.infobar_jsp._jspService(infobar_jsp.java:107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:576)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:621)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
    at org.apache.jsp.templates.tiles_005fw_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f1(tiles_005fw_jsp.java:725)
    at org.apache.jsp.templates.tiles_005fw_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fsubview_005f1(tiles_005fw_jsp.java:699)
    at org.apache.jsp.templates.tiles_005fw_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(tiles_005fw_jsp.java:564)
    at org.apache.jsp.templates.tiles_005fw_jsp._jspService(tiles_005fw_jsp.java:207)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:419)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.dispatch(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:222)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at net.assetool.webapp.filter.MessageFilter.doFilter(MessageFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at net.assetool.webapp.filter.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.clickstream.ClickstreamFilter.doFilter(ClickstreamFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at net.assetool.webapp.filter.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:292)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.SecurityEnforcementFilter.doFilter(SecurityEnforcementFilter.java:197)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:143)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:220)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139)
    at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception getting value of property projectList of base of type : net.assetool.infobardisplay.InfoBarDisplay
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getValue(PropertyResolverImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.ELParserHelper$MyPropertySuffix.evaluate(ELParserHelper.java:535)
    at org.apache.commons.el.ComplexValue.evaluate(ComplexValue.java:145)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:386)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Bean: net.assetool.infobardisplay.InfoBarDisplay, property: projectList
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getProperty(PropertyResolverImpl.java:461)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getValue(PropertyResolverImpl.java:85)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getProperty(PropertyResolverImpl.java:457)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:428)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy55.getProjects(Unknown Source)
    at net.assetool.infobardisplay.InfoBarDisplay.getProjectList(InfoBarDisplay.java:486)
    ... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:342)
    ... 121 more
```

This is the class

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

//Default is read only
@Transactional
public class AuthorisationManagerSecurityImpl extends BaseManager implements
    net.assetool.tabmenu.auth.Security {
  public final static String PERMISSION_CALCULATION = "calculationPerm";

  public final static String PERMISSION_SBC = "navigateSbc";

  // TODO Javadoc
  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public boolean isUserInRole(String pRole) {
    boolean isUserInRole = false;
    FacesContext lContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    AuthorisationManager authorisationManager = (AuthorisationManager) lContext
        .getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(lContext,
            "authorisationManager");

    if (pRole.contains(PERMISSION_SBC)) {
      Long currentProjectPk = authorisationManager.getCurrentProjectPk();
      if (currentProjectPk != null) {
        isUserInRole = authorisationManager.hasUserProjectPermission(
            currentProjectPk, "");
      }
    } else if (pRole.contains(PERMISSION_CALCULATION)) {
      Long currentProjectPk = authorisationManager.getCurrentProjectPk();
      if (currentProjectPk != null) {
        isUserInRole = true;
      }
    } else {
      isUserInRole = authorisationManager.hasUserAnyPermission(pRole);
    }
    return isUserInRole;
  }

}
```

TransactonManager:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" abstract="false" singleton="true" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
      </list>
    </property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>

        <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" abstract="false" singleton="true" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
      <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

We are not getting the session object. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I'm looking at the [source code of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:342)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.orm/3.1.0/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.java#342) and it looks like Spring can't create transation. Try to increase logging level and read logs carefully. Maybe transation manager isn't configred properly.

Comment: Hello Peter, I have edited my post with transation manager's config.

Comment: Set level INFO to org.springframework.orm and org.hibernate and read if everything starts up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved by changing the spring libraries. Initially, we were using spring-framework-3.1.0.RC2. There are few bugs in RC2 release. Now we replaced the RC2 libraries with new spring-framework-3.1.0.RELEASE.